# HTML 5 : Bandwith throttling when uploading a file

Tags: file, html, upload, bandwidth-throttling

I've read that we have a nice solution to upload files and get progress bar in HTML5, but I'm wondering if there is a way to manage throughput and limit bandwidth consumption with the same technology (just to get rid of Flash or Silver-whatever plugins).

Thanks.

Yann